# Why got an error when update property in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I run this Cypher

```
CALL algo.randomWalk.stream(310467,3, 10) YIELD nodeIds 
with algo.getNodeById(nodeIds[3]) as node foreach (n in node| set n.cnt+=1)
```

I get

```
error:Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input '+': expected an identifier character, '.', whitespace, '(' or '=' (line 1, column 128 (offset: 127)) "CALL algo.randomWalk.stream(310467,3, 10) YIELD nodeIds with algo.getNodeById(nodeIds[3]) as node foreach (n in node| set n.cnt+=1)"
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: The exception message is pretty obvious => `set n.cnt = n.cnt + 1`

Comment: could you tell me how to adjust this cypher,cnt is a property of my node

Comment: I wrote you the right way to write it

Comment: not sure what you need the foreach for, as node is a single value not a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+=` is not a valid operator in Cypher. To increment by 1, you have to use the normal SET command, and set it to itself+1 like `SET n.cnt = n.cnt + 1`